# VBO dissapearing, bad Matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, vbo

I'm not sure why but my VBO is disappearing after one frame (initial frame shows it at the origin improperly angled) Below is the code for my matrix class, the draw method, and the vertex shader.

```
Matrix::Matrix() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        values[i] = 0;
    }
}

Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &matrix) {
    Matrix result;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                result.values[i * 4 + j] += this->values[i * 4 + k] * matrix.values[k * 4 + j];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

Matrix Matrix::Perspective(float fov, float aspect, float znear, float zfar) {
    Matrix matrix;

    float xymax = znear * tan(fov * 0.00872664);
    float q = -(zfar * znear) / (zfar - znear);
    float val = znear / xymax;

    matrix.values[0] = val / aspect;
    matrix.values[5] = val;
    matrix.values[10] = q;
    matrix.values[11] = -1;
    matrix.values[14] = 2 * q;

    return matrix;
}

Matrix Matrix::LookAt(Vector3f eye, Vector3f target, Vector3f up) {

    Vector3f zaxis = Vector3f::Normalize(target - eye);
    Vector3f xaxis = Vector3f::Normalize(Vector3f::CrossProduct(up, zaxis));
    Vector3f yaxis = Vector3f::CrossProduct(zaxis, xaxis);
    // vy doesn't need to be normalized because it's a cross product of 2 normalized vectors

    Matrix viewMatrix;
    viewMatrix.values[0]  = xaxis.x;
    viewMatrix.values[1]  = xaxis.y;
    viewMatrix.values[2]  = xaxis.z;
    viewMatrix.values[3]  = 0;

    viewMatrix.values[4]  = yaxis.x;
    viewMatrix.values[5]  = yaxis.y;
    viewMatrix.values[6]  = yaxis.z;
    viewMatrix.values[7]  = 0;

    viewMatrix.values[8]  = zaxis.x;
    viewMatrix.values[9]  = zaxis.y;
    viewMatrix.values[10] = zaxis.z;
    viewMatrix.values[11] = 0;

    viewMatrix.values[12] = 0;
    viewMatrix.values[13] = 0;
    viewMatrix.values[14] = 0;
    viewMatrix.values[15] = 1;

    Matrix translationMatrix = Matrix::Identity();
    translationMatrix.values[12] = -eye.x;
    translationMatrix.values[13] = -eye.y;
    translationMatrix.values[14] = -eye.z;

    return translationMatrix * viewMatrix;
}

Matrix Matrix::Identity() {
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.values[0] = 1;
    matrix.values[5] = 1;
    matrix.values[10] = 1;
    matrix.values[15] = 1;
    return matrix;
}
```

Variables:

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = 
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
GLuint vertexbuffer;
GLuint programID;
```

Draw method:

```
void draw() {
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(programID);

    Matrix projection = Matrix::Perspective(45.0f, (float)(screen_size.x) / screen_size.y, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    Matrix view = Matrix::LookAt(Vector3f(4, 3, 3), Vector3f(0, 0, 0), Vector3f(0, 1, 0));
    Matrix model = Matrix::Identity();
    Matrix mvp = projection * view * model;

    GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "mvp");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp.values);

    int positionId = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionId, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionId);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried unrolling your matrix multiplication loop? To be honest, I would not even try to tell if it is doing the right thing...

Comment: what do you mean unroll my matrix multiplication loop? I've tried passing just the identity matrix and that works fine (get a nice big fat triangle on my screen.) Honestly I feel like i must have done a matrix function wrong, but I copied the code from a bunch of other people asking how to preform the above operations.

Comment: Well I've done a bunch of matrix multiplication implementations and I've also seen a lot, but I have never encountered a loop there. Try something like this http://pastebin.com/RD4Cmdqg .

Comment: well actually I am pretty sure the matrix loop is fine, but I just realized I forgot to use OpenGL error checking (I've done this like 5 times now) and I get an Invalid Operation error right after calling glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp.values)

Comment: honestly I have no idea what is wrong. The identity matrix works great, but if I scale it 1/2 there is no visible difference between identity and scaled identity.

Comment: Then check your multiplication loop. Identity is always easy...if you multiply by 1 erroneously it doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: okay, well I double checked, and the multiplication function is perfectly fine. I'm thinking it's an OpenGL error rather than math.

Comment: Does glGetUniform*(programID, "mvp") return a non-zero number? Also, is mvp.values of type GLfloat*? Did linking the program return any errors? You can use http://code.google.com/p/glintercept/ to try and find the error. It's a re-written opengl implementation that acts as a diagnosis tool. It can usually give you a very good description of what caused an error.

Comment: well, glGetUniform*(...) returns 0 (I assume -1 is failure) mvp.values is of type float* which is basically what GLfloat* is ad there were no errors wen linking the program.

Comment: I have no idea why, but if I replace my matrix with glm::mat4 and it's functions everything works quite swimmingly. But I'd really like to use my own matrix class for this.